# why Typo3 website v10 show empty sitemap xml in frontend

Tags: typo3, typo3-10.x

I'm using a Typo3 website version 10 and the sitemap is not working properly,
i can see the configuration in the typoscript object browser but in the front-end [www.mydomain.ch/?type=1533906435](http://www.mydomain.ch/?type=1533906435) the xml file is blanc.
Frontend screenshot:
[image]

Typoscript object browser screenshot:
[image]

seo extension is installed.
the website is multilangage.

what can be missing so that i see the sitemap ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have solved the problem, i think it was the sourceopt extension installed have a bug, i have update it to the latest version, now i can see the xml sitemap working fine, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If this is all you have, then you are missing some key configuration. You need to specify what should be shown. So, on your TypoScript, based on the [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/XmlSitemap/Index.html#xmlsitemapdataproviders), you should define what pages/extension etc must be shown. For example:

```
plugin.tx_seo {
  config {
    xmlSitemap {
      sitemaps {
        pages {
          config {
            excludedDoktypes = 137, 138
            additionalWhere = AND (no_index = 0 OR no_follow = 0)
            #rootPage = <optionally specify a different root page. (default: rootPageId from site configuration)>
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is an example for the extension news as well, in case you are using it.

```
plugin.tx_seo.config {
    xmlSitemap {
        sitemaps {
            news {
                provider = TYPO3\CMS\Seo\XmlSitemap\RecordsXmlSitemapDataProvider
                config {
                    table = tx_news_domain_model_news
                    additionalWhere =
                    sortField = sorting
                    lastModifiedField = tstamp
                    changeFreqField = sitemap_changefreq
                    priorityField = sitemap_priority
                    pid = 26
                    recursive = 2
                    url {
                        pageId = 25
                        fieldToParameterMap {
                            uid = tx_news_pi1[news]
                        }

                        additionalGetParameters {
                            tx_news_pi1.controller = News
                            tx_news_pi1.action = detail
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here the documentation as well: [Documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/9.2/en-us/Tutorials/BestPractice/Seo/Index.html?highlight=xml#basic-sitemap)

Comment: Thank you for your help, i have included this typoscript in templates, but still no results :(

Comment: then, you could share your code so we can see if something doesnt add up ;)

Comment: Yes sure Aristeidis, what part of the code ? i don't have any special configurations, i just installed seo extension and yoast_seo extension, i didn't write any custom codes.
i already tried to disable yoast, and still the problem is there. empty sitemap.xml

Comment: if your only goal is to get a sitemap, then you do not need yoast. As for the part of the code, the part where you included the TypoScript